# Using Rselenium with firefox and socks5h

Tags: r, firefox, proxy, socks, rselenium

I'm using the RSelenium package to connect to firefox, but I wish to do it via a socks proxy.

In Python, this is achievable using the webdriver package and setting the preferences of the FirefoxProfile, e.g.

    `profile=webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
    profile.set_preference('network.proxy.socks', x.x.x.x)
    profile.set_preference('network.proxy.socks_port', ****)
    browser=webdriver.Firefox(profile)`

However, I can't find how to try set the proxy to be a socks proxy, or to set the socks port in RSelenium. I've tried setting it using the RCurl options, as follows

    `options(RCurlOptions = list(proxy = "socks5h://x.x.x.x:****"))`

but this gives me the following error message

    `Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  : 
  Can't complete SOCKS5 connection to 0.0.0.0:0. (1)`

Has anyone successfully connected to Firefox using a socks proxy using R code?

I am using version 1.3.5 of RSelenium and version 28.0 of Firefox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not tested but something like the following should work:

```
fprof <- makeFirefoxProfile(list(
  "network.proxy.socks" = "squid.home-server"
  , "network.proxy.socks_port" = 3128L
  , "network.proxy.type" = 1L
)
)
remDr <- remoteDriver(extraCapabilities = fprof)
remDr$open()
```

Comment: Many thanks for that. I did try it and it got rid of my original error, however when I go into about:config it I've noted that it updates network.proxy.socks but not network.proxy.socks_port or network.proxy.type. Can these be updated using makeFirefoxProfile?

Comment: @JoeArtisan my apologies integers should be explicitly given so use `3128L` rather than `3128` etc. `network.proxy.type` can be defined in a similar fashion.