# Setting proxy in RSelenium with Chrome Web Driver

Tags: r, web-scraping, proxy, rselenium

I've done a lot of searches. But I haven't found how to set chrome web driver to use proxy yet.

I've found people using phantomjs:
   [Setting proxy in RSelenium with PhantomJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29656217/setting-proxy-in-rselenium-with-phantomjs)

and people using Firefox:
[Using Rselenium with firefox and socks5h](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28670484/using-rselenium-with-firefox-and-socks5h)

But I've found no one using chrome yet. And strangely, there is a `makeFirefoxProfile()` but no `makeChromeProfile` function. So doing it this way is not applicable.

Back to the question. Is there a way to set proxy for chrome in Selenium? Thanks!