# Firefox profile proxy setup inside RSelenium driver

Tags: python, r, selenium-webdriver, proxy, rselenium

I'm using `selenium/standalone-firefox:111.0` docker image with RSelenium `remoteDriver` and need to use proxy inside the browser session.
**First experiment:**
I have tried to pass the proxy info through `extraCapabilities` parameter as follows:

```
firefox_profile <- makeFirefoxProfile(list(network.proxy.http = "host",
                                              network.proxy.http_port = '22225',
                                              network.proxy.type = '1'))
remDr <- remoteDriver(
  remoteServerAddr = "localhost",
  port = 4444L,
  browserName = "firefox",
  extraCapabilities = firefox_profile
)
```

Then I get nothing inside the settings of the Firefox session and my IP is still being shown when I run `remDr$navigate("https://ipinfo.io/")`.

**Second experiment:**
On the other hand, I have tried to reach the Firefox proxy settings using the following code but can't reach the proxy fields inside the connection settings.

```
remDr$open()
remDr$navigate("about:preferences")
webElem <- remDr$findElement("css", "#connectionSettings")$clickElement()
dialogFrame <- remDr$findElement(using = 'name',value = "dialogFrame-1")
dialogFrame$highlightElement()
remDr$findElement("xpath", "//input[@data-l10n-id='connection-proxy-autologin']")$clickElement()
```

I have already tried the following with no success: [Using Rselenium with firefox and socks5h](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28670484/using-rselenium-with-firefox-and-socks5h)

[image]

Comment: You should delete that image and change your proxy password FYI

Comment: yes saw that right after posting, changed it. Thx a lot!

Comment: Did you solve this? I've had firefox proxies work with playwright but I never tried with Selenium

Comment: do you know how to pass the proxy config into firefox ?

Comment: I'm not sure. You can look at how playwright does it I guess or you can switch to playwright.